# Embedded Entities with the ID

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I have created an abstract entity class that defines two concrete subclasses:

```
@Entity(name="Zone")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",
                     discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,
                     length=10)
@Table(name="grZones")
public abstract class ZoneEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    public String getIdent() ...

    @Entity(name="RootZone")
    @DiscriminatorValue(value="root")
    public static class RootZone extends ZoneEntity { ... }

    @Entity(name="Subzone")
    @DiscriminatorValue(value="subzone")
    public static class Subzone extends ZoneEntity { ... }
}
```

And another class that references the abstract zone class:

```
@Entity(name="Device")
@Table(name="grDevices")
public class DeviceEntity {

    public DeviceEntity() { }

    @Id
    @XmlTransient
    public Long getID() { ... }

    @JoinColumn(name = "parent", updatable = true, nullable = false)
    public ZoneEntity getParent() { ... }
}
```

At deployment type (Jboss-7.1.1) I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.graphicreports.amun.habitat.ZoneEntity, at table: grDevices, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(parent)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:467)
```

Is there some annotation that I need to add somewhere to get this to work, or do I have to rethink my database structures?

Many thanks
Steve

Comment: What does the schema you are trying to map to the entities look like?

Comment: @BC2L There is no schema.  The tables are created by JBoss when deployment is successful.  But if I remove DeviceEntity from the deployment then the schema looks like this: `CREATE TABLE grZones (
  type varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  ident varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  abbr varchar(255) default NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (ident)
)` (Quotes removed from table & column names).